# How to hide album art in VLC?

Tags: vlc

Some album art is not, well, conducive to work. How can I stop VLC from displaying any album art, without deleting the actual files on disk?

Answer (score 1):

1. In Preferences → Audio → Effects → Visualization select something other than "Disabled"
2. Start playing
3. In Audio → Visualization (the menu, not the preference) select something other than "Disabled"

Unfortunately VLC disabled visualizations for no reason just now, so I'm hoping for a more permanent solution.